# Override prose 40rem max-width and margin auto

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm playing around with Tailwind and using the typography plugin. I'm running into issues when trying to override the margins and max-width prose sets on content.

In my tailwind-typography.js file I have the following setup:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            typography: () => ({
                

                DEFAULT: {
                    css: [
                        {
                            
                           maxWidth: false,
                           maxWidth: '100ch', 
                            blockquote: {
                                borderLeftStyle: 'solid',
                            },

                            
                            'blockquote > cite': {
                                color: 'var(--tw-prose-body)',
                                fontStyle: 'normal',
                                fontWeight: '400',
                            },
                            'blockquote > cite::before': {
                                content: '"\\2014"',
                            },

                            hr: {
                                borderBottom: 'none',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }),
        },
    },
};
```

Despite this, in any div that calls prose I'm seeing the following CSS regardless of the width of that div, size of the text or character limit set in the config. I get a 40rem max-width.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 40rem;
```

Is there an elegant way to override this? Setting the class 'max-w-none' on the div doesn't work?

Comment: From your described setup I cannot see any margin added to any `<div>`. And the only `max-width` is coming from your `100ch` value. https://play.tailwindcss.com/58YgxQI3Fc Can you check the styles where they are coming from in dev tools?

Comment: Thanks for that. You're right. I was working with _tailwind which has added its own styles elsewhere in a separate file. If it wasn't for your prompt I'd still be scratching my head.